# Theoretical limit to how many API requests AWS API Gateway can handle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How big can AWS API Gateway scale? I'm wondering how is it able to handle such large volumes of API requests? Under the hood it has to translate the request and see what endpoint its going and potentially do any validation on the headers so this takes some compute power. Is there any theoretical limit to how many requests a single endpoint can handle served through AWS API Gateway? Say I wanted to run an endpoint behind API Gateway - can it handle like 5,000,000,000,000 requests/second?

Answer (score -1):

You may check the API Gateway account-level quotas here:
[Amazon API Gateway quotas and important notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#apigateway-account-level-limits-table)

Good Day,
Hiren